# Bash script calls vi for manual editing, then script resumes?

Tags: bash, automation, text-editor, vi

I wrote a script that creates a backup of a text file, and a second script that verifies some syntax in text file using SED.

In the middle, there is a manual process: Users edit the original file adding some strings. This process must remain manual.

I would like to merge my two scripts so the backup is created, vi is open for the user, when the user is done editing the file, the script resumes doing the syntax verification.

I am learning by doing, but really do not know how to code the "open vi, wait for the user to do his editing, take control over and resume with verification" part.

I read there is a function called system (in Perl) that could be used, but my code is in BASH.

Any suggestions on how to get this done in BASH? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, each statement is essentially like an implicit call to `system` (unless it's a builtin shell command) since shell scripts are designed to make it easy to run other programs.

```
backup some_file.txt
vi some_file.txt  # The script blocks until the user exits vi
verify_syntax some_file.txt
```

The only difference between using `vi` and a command like `ls` is that `ls` will do its thing and exit without user intervention, while `vi` (or any interactive command) will run until the user explicitly exits.