# Command line program defer to default text editor

Tags: java, bash, shell, text-editor

I have a workflow for which I want users to be able to edit some "free-form" text.  If this were on a webform, imagine this being a `<textarea>`.  Imagine, for example you're filling out a user profile.  For fields such as "name" a simple prompt where users continue with the ENTER key is great.  But for something like a "bio" field, we need to capture linebreaks.

How can this be done generally?

(Ideally, my tool will be in either bash, Python, Ruby or Java but getting the workflow to be friendly is more important than the tools used to create it.  Also, I happen to be in a Ubuntu environment.)

**Update:**
The context is that I'll be logging in to systems over SSH and running through this workflow.  For that reason, I need to stick with a shell-friendly tool.  I'm happy to use any tool necessary to get the job done.  I'm not asking for opinions on what would be ask.  I simply don't know the right terminology or techniques to defer to something like `vim` in the middle of executing a prompt/response style command-line application.

Comment: I'd go with Java, since any OS with a JRE can run a Java program. Then you can use Swing or possibly JavaFX. If you decide to go with Swing then look at [javax.swing.JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) or [JTextEditor/Pane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html). Also this question could be closed due to it being "primarily opinion based".

Comment: Both "too broad" and "primarily opinion based".

Comment: I'm definitely not asking how to make a GUI with a text area.  I'm asking how to capture multiline input within the context of a command-line program.  I'll make some edits to the question to clarify.

Comment: You can easily call something like vi in a bash script and have your script wait for the user to exit vi. Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686006/bash-script-calls-vi-for-manual-editing-then-script-resumes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to handle this is indeed to launch the user's favorite (command-line) text editor on their behalf, wait for them to finish their editing and then continue with your own business using the user input. The process used for `git commit` is a very well-known example.

Your program will have to do the following steps.

- Create a temporary file. You can use the `mktemp` program to do this from a shell script.

  Consider putting a `trap` in place that deletes the file if your script gets killed during the process so you don't litter the user's file system. (Since `mktemp` will create the file in `/tmp/` by default and everything in that directory is usually purged on a regular schedule, it's not that bad, anyway.)
- If you don't want the user to start out with an empty file but provide them with a template to start from, write any such text to the file now.
- Fire up the user's favorite editor to open that file. Your script will block until the user closes the editor.

  The interesting question is of course how to decide what program to launch. The generally agreed upon technique is to try the following options in that order.

  - any command listed in an environment variable `PACKAGE_EDITOR` where you substitute the name of your application for `PACKAGE`
  - any command listed in the environment variable `EDITOR`
  - a standard editor like `vi`
  - error out

  By trying an environment variable that is specific to your application before the generic `EDITOR` variable, users can special-case those applications for which they need a different editor than their default one.

  As [chrylis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis) has pointed out in the comments, you may also check an environment variable named `VISUAL` that (according to [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/visual-vs-editor-whats-the-difference)) was once used to provide a way to use a more advanced editor on video terminals that would be capable of running it.
- Read back the contents of the file. Think about giving the user an option to abort the process during the edit. Git, for example, interprets saving an empty file as a request for abortion.
- Remove the temporary file.

Don't forget to document the influence of the environment variables properly for your users.

Here is a simple example you can play with.

```
#! /bin/bash -eu

edit=
tempfile=

if [ "${EXAMPLE_EDITOR:+set}" = set ]
then
    edit="${EXAMPLE_EDITOR}"
elif [ "${EDITOR:+set}" = set ]
then
    edit="${EDITOR}"
else
    edit='vi'
fi

function cleanup {
    [ -z "${tempfile}" ] || rm -f "${tempfile}"
}

trap cleanup EXIT

tempfile="$(mktemp)"

cat <<EOF > "${tempfile}"
# Please edit this file to contain your list of noble wishes, then
# save and exit the editor.  If you decide to abort the process,
# delete everything and save an empty file.
EOF

${edit} "${tempfile}" || {
    echo "Editing command '${edit} ${tempfile}' is not working or" \
         "was aborted on purpose" >&2
    exit 1
}

if [ ! -s "${tempfile}" ]
then
    echo "Aborting due to empty wish list" >&2
    exit 1
fi

# Do something with the list of noble wishes...
```

Note that I'm not quoting the expansion of `${edit}` so things like `EDITOR='emacs -nw'` are also possible.

Comment: You should also check `VISUAL`.

Comment: @chrylis I've never seen that. Can you give an example of an application that makes use of it? Is it meant to be used only when a GUI is available?

Comment: Among other programs, the ordinary `visudo` does. It's not meant for GUI but for full-screen terminals; `VISUAL` was used with a CRT terminal, while `EDITOR` was for actual line printers that couldn't even display `vi`.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/visual-vs-editor-whats-the-difference

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for the info. I have added that to my answer.